# How many errors are stored in the table USER_ERRORS for a package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I compiled a package using the command

```
ALTER PACKAGE PKG_NAME COMPILE PACKAGE;
```

It had errors because some tables were not present. But all the non existent tables are not shown in USER_ERRORS. If I create the tables which are shown as non existing and compile the package again, then new errors are coming showing that some other tables are not existing. So is there any limit on the number of records in USER_ERRORS for a package or does Oracle stop compiling after a fixed number of errors are present?

Answer (score 1):

"Does Oracle stop compiling after a fixed number of errors are present?"

I don't think so, but I believe it does stop compiling when it hits the first error in a particular block / statement.

So a block of code could have multiple errors but only the first will be reported.  As you fix the errors, new ones in the same block will be revealed.

Comment: There are errors in blocks unrelated to the ones in which errors are shown presently. But those are not shown until the current errors are solved.

Comment: The last error was due to a DBlink. Is it because of that?